# When linking in 2 openssl's with libcurl : error setting certificate verify locations

Tags: c++, c, curl, openssl, libcurl

I am using libcurl4-openssl-dev which is using system openssl, I assume. However when I link it to a binary that is also linked to my own locally built openssl (using for other things), when trying to send a http request I get

```
error setting certificate verify locations
```

I do not get this issue if the locally built openssl is not linked to the binary.

Can someone explain to me what could be happening here? Let me know if more info is needed.

Comment: Have you set `CURL_CA_BUNDLE` to point to the relevant certs?

Comment: No but it finds it fine if my locally built openssl is not linked into the binary.

Comment: It's possible your distro has a custom certificate location, that the curl you built can't find.

Comment: I didn't build curl. I am on ubuntu 16.04.